# volley library displaying the data not stored in the json data

Tags: android, eclipse

I am having problem with volley library. I dont understand where i am getting all the values from in the application even the internet is not accessible and the data is not available in the api itself. I tried to clear the cache but nothing is working. Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks

```
private void makeJsonObjReq() {
    //Log.e("makeJsonobjReq method", "inside");
    pinfo = new PostsInfo();
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET,
            Const.URL_JSON_ARRAY, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    JSONArray jArray;
                    Log.e(TAG +"", " rrr "+ response.toString());
                    try {
                        Log.e(TAG, "" + response.getInt("count") + " " + response.getInt("pages") + " " + response.getInt("page"));
                        for (int i = response.getInt("page"); i <= response.getInt("pages"); i++) {
                            jArray = response.getJSONArray("results");
                            for (int j = 0; j < response.getInt("count"); j++) {
                                try {

                                        a_fetch_data.open();
                                        JSONObject json =  jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                        Log.e(TAG +" no of count in array", "i = "+ json.getString("id"));
                                        //jsonObjectValue(json);

                                    }
                                    catch (JSONException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                }
                            Log.e(TAG, "Array "+ " Completed ");
                            }
                        }
                         catch (JSONException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                }
            });

    /*Adding request to request queue*/
    ApplicationController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq,
            "jobj_req");

    ApplicationController.getInstance().getRequestQueue().getCache().remove("jobj_req");
}
```

api :http://bumpintomums.com.au/wp-content/themes/bumpii/API/get_data.php

The problem is, this method returns a response even though i am not connected to internet and i have not instantiated any cache work here.

Comment: Post some code and what you thought would happen vs what is happening

Comment: which api are u using? show us your volley code, which data u want to recieve?